# How can i search for a particular date for eg: '2013-10-22' from sql

Tags: sql, oracle

How can i search for a particular date for eg: '2013-10-22' from sql developer/Oracle rdbms

If the field shows date+time and , if i need to search for a particular date alone without including the time how should the query be?

Comment: What dbms are you using? Answers will vary depending on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server you can try like this:-

```
 select * from myTable
 where myColumn=to_date('22-Oct-13');
```

or

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE table.daterecord >= TO_DATE('22-Oct-2013', 'DD-MON-RRRR')
   AND table.daterecord < TO_DATE('23-Oct-2013', 'DD-MON-RRRR')
```

or

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE TRUNC(table.daterecord) = TO_DATE('23-Oct-2013', 'DD-MON-RRRR')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE TRUNC(MyDateTime) = TO_DATE('01/JAN/2011','dd/mon/yyyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a SQL question. Here is the query how to search for date in datetime column.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE convert(VARCHAR(10),DateTimeColumn,121) = '2013-10-22'
```

Replace MyTable with the name of your table.
Replace DateTimeColumn with the column name you want to perform the date lookup against.

How do I know it's date code "121", how did I come up with this code, etc? I suggest you do some google research for SQL datetime conversion. For your convience, here is a useful link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx. I hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions.